# Chef recipe execution order

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, silent-installer

following is a recipe which I use to copy and install a software on my windows server.

```rb
batch "Get installed software list" do
  code "wmic /output:C:\\InstallList.txt product get name,version"
end

if File.read('C:/InstallList.txt', mode: 'r:BOM|UTF-16:UTF-8') =~ /.NET Framework 4/
  print "Dotnet framework 4 is already installed."
else
  remote_file 'c:/repo/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe' do
    source 'file:////10.132.17.53/e$/CHEFREPO/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe'
  end
  batch "Install Dotnet" do
    cwd 'c:/repo/'
    code <<-EOH
        dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe  #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['passive']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['CEIPconsent']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['chainingpackage']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['createlayout']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['lcid']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['log']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['msioptions']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['norestart']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['promptrestart']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['quit']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['repair']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['serialdownload']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['uninstall']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['parameterfolder']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['NoSetUpVersionCheck']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['uninstallpatch']} 
        del dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe

    EOH
    not_if {File.read('c:/InstallList.txt', mode: 'r:BOM|UTF-16:UTF-8') =~ /.NET Framework 4/}
  end
end
```

The batch resource, created a text file which contains the list of already installed software. Then I read this file to check if the software is already installed. It it is, I print a message. Else the recipe moves into my else part, where I download the setup from remote repository and then install it using silent installation.
But on the client run, I get an error as following :

```
[2014-08-22T05:26:38-07:00] FATAL: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - C:
/InstallList.txt
```

My client is somehow executing the `File.read` code in the if block, before executing the first batch `resource("Get installed Software List")`. Any ideas what might be going wrong and a workaround for the same.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your `if` code is executed during compile phase, while your `batch` ressource is executed within the converge phase see [details here](http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_nodes_chef_run.html).

You can achieve what you wish by running the `batch` resource at compile time like:

```rb
batch "Get installed software list" do
  code "wmic /output:C:\\InstallList.txt product get name,version"
  action :nothing
end.run_action(:run)
```

In your case including your code in the `not_if` block and getting rid of the if/else part is another option
i.e:

```rb
remote_file 'c:/repo/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe' do
  source 'file:////10.132.17.53/e$/CHEFREPO/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe'
end

batch "Install Dotnet" do
  cwd 'c:/repo/'
  code <<-EOH
    dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe  #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['passive']} #                 {node['mycloud_dotnet']['CEIPconsent']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['chainingpackage']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['createlayout']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['lcid']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['log']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['msioptions']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['norestart']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['promptrestart']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['quit']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['repair']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['serialdownload']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['uninstall']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['parameterfolder']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['NoSetUpVersionCheck']} #{node['mycloud_dotnet']['uninstallpatch']} 
    del dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe
  EOH
  not_if { `wmic /output:C:\\InstallList.txt product get name,version` =~ /.NET Framework 4/ }
end
```

The remote file could have a guard on it to avoid downloading each time:

```rb
not_if { File::exists(...) }
```

Comment: The method to run the batch resource at compile time worked charms. but i guess there is an error in the not_if condition. While uploading the cookbook, it is giving a sntax error : 'Unexpected }'

Comment: Thanks @sethvargo for the refining the answer and fixing the guard line.