# access updated node attributes in cookbook recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am new to chef environment. And working on a simple cookbook.

To simplify, I have following attributes in:

attributes/default.rb:

```
default[:user1] = ""
default[:user2] = ""
default[:filename] = ""
```

recipes/default.rb:
At run time, I get a filename from another cookbook and I have to extract users from that file.

```
file = "#{node[:filename]}"

ruby_block 'extract userdata' do
  block do
    json = File.read(file)
    obj = JSON.parse(json)

    userdata = obj['users']

    if userdata.empty?
      raise "Errors: userdata not available"
    else
      node.override[:user1] = userdata['user1']
      node.override[:user2] = userdata['user2']
    end
  end
  puts "user1: #{node[:user1]}"
  puts "user2: #{node[:user2]}"
  action :run
end
```

logs (puts) from above block at runtime do fetch me usernames correctly.

Now, I am trying to use above two updated attributes as below in further down the cookbook recipe.

```
user1 = #{node[:user1]}
user2 = #{node[:user2]}
```

But these two values are coming out to be empty as if they are not set/overriden.

Please suggest how can I get updated data.

Comment: Quite long to explain, but you're hit by the "two pass run" aka "compile vs converge time" problem. Part of your code is run at compile time, whereas other parts are run at converge time. See [this](http://docs.chef.io/chef_client.html#the-chef-client-title-run) for how the run is done. (and do a search with the names I provided, you'll find answers)

Answer (score 2):

I'll summarize the following answers (which gives another views on the same problem) and gives an example on your specific case.

- [Using a Ruby block to assign variables in chef recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424244/using-a-ruby-block-to-assign-variables-in-chef-recipe)
- [Chef recipe execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447227/chef-recipe-execution-order)

---

You're problem here is [compile time versus converge time](http://docs.chef.io/chef_client.html#the-chef-client-title-run)

What happens here is that the recipe and the resources are evaluated at compile time and the content of your `ruby_block` resource is evaluated at converge time.

There's 2 solutions to get around this:

- First option is to run your ruby_block at compile time:

  ```
  ruby_block 'extract userdata' do
    block do
      json = File.read(file)
      obj = JSON.parse(json)

      userdata = obj['users']

      if userdata.empty?
        raise "Errors: userdata not available"
      else
        node.override[:user1] = userdata['user1']
        node.override[:user2] = userdata['user2']
      end
    end
    puts "user1: #{node[:user1]}"
    puts "user2: #{node[:user2]}"
    action :nothing
  end.run_action(:run)
  ```

  Notice the `action :nothing` to avoid the resource to be executed at converge time too and the `.run_action(:run)` which tell the evaluation to run this resource as soon as it's evaluated.
- Second option is to use [lazy evaluation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#lazy-attribute-evaluation) in other resources like this:

  ```
  execute "Do something" do
    command lazy { "/path/command #{node['user1]}" }
  end
  ```

  The `lazy {}` has to encompass the whole attribute value, not just the variable or it will throw an error.

I advise to preferably use option 2 as much as possible. Doing things at compile time could end up in a difficult run to understand when it goes wrong as actions are taken in two different flows.

I recommend using string to access node attributes, single quoted when fixed text, double quoted when you need interpolation as symbols can get unexpected behaviors sometimes if an attribute name match an existing symbol in the recipe DSL namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try add `node.save` after override/set new values to the attributes in the code block.

```
if userdata.empty?
  raise "Errors: userdata not available"
else
  node.override[:user1] = userdata['user1']
  node.override[:user2] = userdata['user2']
  node.save
end
```

Comment: This won't fix the problem as the resources after will be evaluated at compile time when the block has not been evaluated, so they will still use old values.

Comment: And it's of no use in this case, the `override` method update the node object, the use case to `node.save` is to update the node object on chef-server to be sure it's updated even if the run fail later, this allow using attributes as guards to not redo an install, or in long runs to make the node available in search to other nodes.